# Instead of played automatically, Youtube video do nothing or show suggested videos

Tags: javascript, video, browser, cross-browser, embedded-video

What I want to do is to play an embedded Youtube video at a certain moment of time.  To this end, at the given time I run the javascript code

document.getElementById("video").src= "https://www.youtube.com/embed/...?autoplay=1&start=212";

where video is my iframe. 
Now the problem - in one browser (IE) it works as it should, the video automatically starts in the given moment. Instead, in Chrome it doesn's start, but show suggested videos - see the picture. It shows suggested not **after** playing the video, but **instead** of playing. In mobile browsers (Samsung and Ghostery) it just appears but doesn't play. 
What could be the reason for this behavior? Could it be something related to settings of my gmail (and thus youtube) accounts, or browser settings?

Comment: My code is very simple. First, I put an iframe with the paused video:


`<iframe width="560" height="315" id="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?&amp;start=212" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>`

Comment: And after I run the video at a given moment (when it is  59 seconds in this case)


`<script>

var now = new Date();

if (now.getSeconds()==59){

document.getElementById("viedao").src= "https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&amp;start=212";

} else { setTimeout(function(){

document.getElementById("viedo").src= "https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&amp;start=212";
}, 1000*(59-now.getSeconds()));

}

</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Please add your code and screenshots for a better understanding of the issue. Also, I think you should check out [Youtube iFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). It will give you the functionality you are looking for. Try out this, it works for Chrome, IE, Firefox. Maybe you will need to check mobile options though.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
        <div id="player"></div>

        <script>
          // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
          var tag = document.createElement('script');

          tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
          var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

          // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
          //    after the API code downloads.
          var player;
          function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
              height: '390',
              width: '640',
              videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
              playerVars: {
                'autoplay': 1,
                'start' : 212
              },
              events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady
              }
            });
          }

          // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
          function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
          }
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank, but your code results in exactly the same outcome. In Chrome it shows the video that is paused and has suggested videos on it. So it doesn't play automatically. 

<iframe width="560" height="315" id="viedo" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gk37rm8Icuo?&amp;start=212" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>

I added screenshots, but they're not here - probably because I'm not allowed to add images yet.

Comment: Screenshot of what I get in Chrome instead of autoplaying video https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPQ9a.jpg

Comment: Oh! that's weird, can you see your console log and see what error(if any) you are getting when the video is paused in chrome? I think that will help narrow down the problem.